# System.InvalidCastException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll - AutoCompleteMode textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to auto complete source textbox, but i'm getting this error:

> Exception Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidCastException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll ("Interface not registered Failed to find proxy registration for IID: {EAC04BC0-3791-11D2-BB95-0060977B464C}.") System.InvalidCastException

all this happened when change AutoCompleteMode, and i don't know why, the code was working fine before, but now i'm facing this error.

this is my code :

```
Conn.Open()
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT MaterialName FROM Materials where SANF = @SANF", Conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SANF", "fix_parts")
Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds, "list")

    Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
Dim i As Integer
MsgBox(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count)
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        col.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("MaterialName").ToString())
    Next
    Conn.Close()
    TxTMaterialName.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    TxTMaterialName.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
    TxTMaterialName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

I'm getting the error here :

```
TxTMaterialName.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
```

[image]

Comment: Try it with a `List(Of String)` instead of a `AutoCompleteStringCollection`:  `Dim col As New List(Of String) (...) TxTMaterialName.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(col.ToArray())`

Comment: Is this code executed in a thread other than UI thread?

Comment: @Jimi, NO , this code in method called autocomplete and I'm call it in form load

Comment: Then it should work. Close the connection before enumerating the Table content (and verify whether it does contain something that can be used as an AutoComplete source).

Comment: @Jimi, i tried to do what you told me  in the first comment and I'm getting the same error. and can you explain more please??
also I added the full error take a look.

Comment: I dont's see a code update. Anyway, this a strange failure. It's related to a missing registration of the `IAutoComplete2` interface. This should happen only for `Shell32.dll` versions before `5.0` (Windows XP era). On what System are you trying to run this application? Also, check the `Shell32.dll` version. You can find it in `\Windows\System32\`. If this is the case, the AutoComplete feature should also be missing in other related System objects (ComboBoxes, for example). Do you have AutoComplete enabled in the RUN dialog (WIn+R)?

Comment: @Jimi, I'm running it on win 10 , what making this not possible is that the code work fine in the same project before 4 days, and i continued work on the project, today I was testing it, and I faced this error, also I have a backup version of the same project it work fine in it. but in the latest version of the project i have the error, the Shell32.dll is version 10 on my OS, when i tried the code in new project its work fine also.

Comment: Try to re-register `shell32.dll` (`regsvr32.exe`). Maybe something went wrong with your registry. I can't imagine what, but it doesn't hurt trying it.

Comment: @Jimi how can i do that ??

Comment: Open an elevated `cmd.exe` (`Win+R -> cmd`) then, in the console, write `regsvr32.exe shell32.dll` and execute. Have you installed something recently? An update of some kind?

Comment: @Jimi I re-registered shell32.dll but unfortunately the problem still existed :(

Comment: Did you check out whether you have AutoComplete enabled in the ComboBox of the RUN dialog you just opened? Try writing `c` inside it and see if `cmd.exe` is shown in the AutoComplete list. Another thing you could try is targeting another Framework version, the latest available, better if it's FW 4.7.1. or 4.7.2, clean the solution, rebuild and retry.

Comment: @Jimi how to check if AutoComplete is enabled ?? and is this for the current project ??( because in the other project the AutoComplete is working fine), Im using `textbox` not `combobox `- where i should type `c` and where should I see cmd.exe, excuse my questions I'm little lost here

Comment: @Jimi I remembered that I deleted VBIED reference from my project, is this the problem ?? and I'm trying to add it agin I added the Microsoft.Vbe.Interop , but also didn't work